# Does SQL Developer GUI use an encoding?

Tags: user-interface, encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL Developer and I have a doubt about displaying data in the SQL Developer GUI. Indeed, I have an encoding concern, and I wanted to check the real state of the data, because I think that maybe the SQL Developer GUI also uses an encoding....
I don't know if my question is clear?

Comment: Unless it displays raw bytes to you, it must also “use an encoding” in some way or another, yes. Clarify your specific concern a bit…?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL Developer is a Java application, everything we do is 'Unicode'

That being said, when you open or create a file, you most definitely cause an 'encoding' to be set.

What most folks run into, problem-wise, is using a FONT that doesn't support the characterset being used in their database.

This setting affects display of BOTH your code and your data.

[image]

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and I am the product manager for SQL Developer.*